# JSON terminating with uncaught exception of type std::domain_error: type must be number, but is null

Tags: c++, json

I have a modeling code that keeps giving me a domain_error when I try to run it and when I try to debug I can't figure out why it is occurring.  Admittedly I am pretty new to c++, and completely new to JSON so any help would be greatly appreciated.
The main() code:

```
int main() {
    AirPlenum testair;

    string jsonconststr = zrein::readtxtfile("HyperConstants.json");
    json::json payload, constants, parameters;
    constants = json::json::parse(jsonconststr);

    parameters["rpm"] = 689;
    parameters["PreviousRhot"] = 1;
    parameters["Aexit"] = 25;
    parameters["Cd"] = 5;
    parameters["time0"] = 0.0;
    parameters["time1"] = 0.01;
    parameters["MdotIn"] = 82;
    parameters["PreviousTtankout"] = 10;
    parameters["Tin"] = 795;
    parameters["Pin"] = 6500;
    parameters["Ain"] = 25;
    parameters["Asin"] = 24;
    parameters["d1"] = 6;
    parameters["dins"] = 5;
    parameters["PreviousTsurf"] = 0.0;
    parameters["Vm"] = 1;

    payload["Constants"] = constants;
    payload["Parameters"] = parameters;

    string jpayload = payload.dump(4);

    string results = testair.runModel(jpayload);   //Here is where the issue happens

    cout << endl << "Air Plenum Results" << endl;
    cout << json::json::parse(results)["Parameters"].dump(4) << endl;

    payload.clear();
    parameters.clear();
    results.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

The line having issues calls upon this:

```
std::string AirPlenum::runModel(std::string payload)
{json::json jsonpayload=json::json::parse(payload);
json::json results=runModel(jsonpayload);
return results.dump(4);}
```

And the runModel(jsonpayload) is a rather big section so I am hoping that the issue is within what I posted above.  I am getting an exit code of 6 (CLion) which from what I can find online indicates there might be a problem with my links somewhere, but I am not seeing it.

EDIT: so I ended up commenting out one of my parameters and retyping it exactly on the line below and for some reason it now works.

Comment: We have no way of knowing what library you're using here. Please present a [MCVE].

Comment: _"the runModel(jsonpayload) is a rather big section so I am hoping that the issue is within what I posted above"_ Don't "hope" — spend some time narrowing down the problem, to result in a [MCVE].